# How to convert Kanji back to Kana?

Tags: software-recommendation, language-support, japanese, kanji

I am learning Japanese, but I haven't really learnt much Kanji yet, though I know a lot of the spoken stuff and can read Hiragana and Katakana. So I was wondering if there is some tool that can be given Kanji and will convert it back to Hiragana (like Anthy converts from Hiragana to Kanji)?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kakasi is the one for Linux.

Kakashi
http://kakasi.namazu.org/index.html.en (In English)

First download the source file http://kakasi.namazu.org/stable/kakasi-2.3.6.tar.gz

```
% gzip -dc kakasi-2.3.5.tar.gz | tar xvf -
% cd kakasi-2.3.5
% ./configure
% make
% su
# make install
```

I see them often online web API. For example, Kanji to hiragana web page
http://tool.stabucky.com/convert/kanji2kana.php

These applications do the other way of Japanese input method does.
Application builders export the dictionary somehow and build a database from them, in my opinion.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I am sorry honestly I don't know what is preferable answer at the moment, I'll learn from other answers.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with some specific details.